# Why do some movie remasters replace the original sound effects with new ones?

Tags: sound-effects

Why do some movie remasters (and I wonder if there are TV shows remastered this way too) replace the original sound effects with new ones?

For instance some movies edit the gun sounds in the original master to digital gun sounds which sometimes sound stronger.

*The Godfather* did this.  I think they do it with THX or something.

Comment: THX is a system for ensuring adequate playback technology for audio - it has nothing to do with recording and mastering.

Answer (score 3):

Remastering a video is done by getting the original analog film and scanning it in at least 2K resolution, but most often in 4K, sometimes in 8K. A new digital scan in such high quality is later edited to remove any damages done to the analog film, with some color restoration and correction also added in the process. This can only be done to an analog film. The audio is recorded on some other storage device or printed on the analog film. But this means that the waveform is saved as it was recorded originally. And such waveform cannot be scanned to be in higher quality, you can only add some noise reduction or make it louder or quieter. This means, if you have a low-quality gun sound, the only way to make it sound better, is to replace it with a newly recorded one.